# Grab registration data from telegram bot

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I'm trying to create a Telegram API bot for clients registration , so I chose the ' setWebHook ' method and wrote some codes :

```
<?php

include("config.php");

$content = file_get_contents("php://input");
$update = json_decode($content, true);
$user_id = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];

if( $update["message"]["text"] == "/start" OR $update["message"]["text"] == "/menu" ){
    $keyboard = array(    
        'keyboard' => array(
             array(" Register"," Login")    
             ),'one_time_keyboard'=>true,'resize_keyboard'=>true);  
    $replyKeyboard = json_encode($keyboard);

    $replyMessage = "Hello 
    Welcome to our bot ✋
    What do you want to do ?
    .
    ";
}

if( $update["message"]["text"] == " Register"){

     $replyMessage = "Please enter username :";
}

$url = $bot_url.'sendMessage';
$data = array('chat_id' => $user_id,'text' => $replyMessage,'parse_mode' => 'Markdown','reply_markup' => $replyKeyboard );
    $options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($data),
            )
        );
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$update = @file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

?>
```

Ok so the robot shows the options for register or login , and when you choose register , it asks you username. It's ok up to here but ,

what I have to do for the rest of the registration process ??

How should I grab username and store it in database and after that grab password and store it and for other informations ?

I appreciate any logical ways for registering by telegram bots.

I wish I could completely describe my problem , I need your help my friends.
Thank you

( config.php includes database and bot token information )

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your question these are some tips maybe helpful for you:

> Each message that delivers from telegram (users) have an id that tell which user sends the message(==`chat_id` a unique number).
>
> Your bot should log messages and save the important parts of messages in a db. In this manner you have a track of user's conversation with your bot and you can recognize that for which question of your bot ,user answers. If you look for each `Json` object delivers from telegram you can see which data telegram reveals from user.

Comment: Thank you for your answer my friend , I'v been thinking of that myself , but I think there are some other more logical ways to do that , even without recognizing registration proccess status ... I'm waiting for other friends to add their issues about my question.

Comment: There is no need for registration at all. When somebody open a chat window with your bot, his/her unique `chat_id` and `sender_id` comes with all messages.As I know your bot should handle all messages and interpret them.`message_id` is something useful too which shows order of messages that user or your bot send to each other.